# Calling only the super method on Override class

Tags: java

I see this code snippet in a Jenkins plugin and I think that it is no-op

```
  @Override
  public DescriptorImpl getDescriptor() {
    return (DescriptorImpl)super.getDescriptor();
  }
```

Any reason that this might be essential and cannot be nuked from the code?

Comment: What's the return type of the parent method? Maybe the reason is the cast, to guarantee the return type and not force callers to do the cast?

Comment: Thanks! That was it. It was overriding the return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During an override, you can modify the return type (if the new return type is a subclass of the old return type).
For example :

```
public class A {
  public Number getNumber() { /* ... */ } ;
}

public class B extends A {
  @Override
  public Integer getNumber() { /* ... */ } ;
}
```

In your sample, `super.getDescriptor()` may always return a `DescriptorImpl` object, so you can override the method to avoid some cast in your code.